# scrolling entire screen with UIScrollview and UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I am trying to build this view where I have a UI Image view with some labels below it. And then Below this I have a Collection view which has a few items. I am struggling to figure out how I could have this view such that the whole screen keeps scrolling up once i get to the collection view.

Right now, the image view and the labels below scroll, but then the collection view only scrolls within its constraints. What I want is the entire screen to scroll up so the collection view items fill the screen up. I have seen several other replies to similar questions but am unable to follow it.
[image: Storybaord screenshot below]

[image: View controller setup]

Can someone help with what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the best practice on mobile programming, you should not have a scrollable view in another scrollable view. If you do so, you will have the problem as you described that your child collection view starts to scroll while other elements like your imageview and labels stay there.

To achieve your point, you can simply use a collection view and have custom cells. Now your entire window has only one scrollable view so it looks better. Then you are basically have different cell types. On top you have a collection cell as image, then you have few collection cell as labels, and so on.